# Nestjs using discovery package to modify controller?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

For my api I am trying to add a decorator `@ApiBearerAuth()` to all my controllers. However I would like to have a way to do this globally so that each time I create a controller this is already handled for me.

Doing some research it looks like this package https://github.com/golevelup/nestjs/tree/master/packages/discovery
could work. However I am unable to figure out how I can actually change the metadata on the controller to include the `@ApiBearerAuth()` suing this package.